# Получить дату из строчки. Неправильный месяц

Tags: java

Получаю дату из строки:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2021-03-07"));
System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-"+calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
```

Получаю результат: `2021-2`, а нужно `2021-3`

И так с каждым месяцем ( выводи на 1 меньше ) в чем проблема?

Comment: счёт месяцев начинается с 0

Comment: @azlov и зачем так сделали?

Comment: можете прочесть интересный ответ здесь : https://coderoad.ru/344380/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%86-0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5-Java

Answer (score 2):

Такой способ предполагает [меньшее количество ошибок](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18002968).
Из [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set(int,%20int)):

> Значение месяца отсчитывается от 0. например, 0 для января.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-"+(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1));
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119765/discussion-on-answer-by-de-bug------).